# In which department total no of project is greater than 40% of overall project

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm having a HR table in hive database with different columns, two of them are department and number_of_projects. The query I need to find is "In which department total number of projects is greater than 10% of overall project"

I have written code as below:

```
SELECT department, 
       SUM(Number_Of_projects) as total_projects_dep 
  FROM Hr 
 GROUP BY department 
HAVING SUM(Number_Of_projects) > (SELECT CAST(0.1*SUM(Number_Of_projects)AS INT) FROM hr);
```

hive is throwing following error:

> FAILED: ParseException line 1:126 cannot recognize input near 'SELECT'
>   'CAST' '(' in expression specification

The same query I have executed in mysql, its working fine and giving correct result. Whereas hive is not accepting greater than symbol between queries.

Can some one guide me how to alter the above query to work in hive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using analytics functions:

```
SELECT department, total_projects_dep 
FROM       
(
SELECT department, 
       SUM(Number_Of_projects) over(partition by department) as total_projects_dep, 
       SUM(Number_Of_projects) over()                        as total_projects
  FROM Hr
)s
WHERE total_projects_dep > CAST(0.1*total_projects AS INT)
GROUP BY department, total_projects_dep --this can be removed if there is only one record per department
```

;